# Jenkins job incorrectly connecting to localhost

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My jenkins job is showing this error when building coverage report.

[INFO] Connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1:6300[INFO] Connection refused (Connection refused)
[INFO] Connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1:6300[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.7:dump (default-cli) on project CodeCoverage: Unable to dump coverage data: Connection refused (Connection refused) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

I was advised to Add "wipe out repository & force clone" in config in source code management but this jenkins job doesn't have the source code management option. Could anyone please help? Thank you

Coverage report is failing because it is trying to connect to localhost.

Comment: Is this a freestyle job or declarative pipeline?